# django admin colon syntax in template tags and in reverse function

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin, reverse

While learning with Django by Example, I have found something I don't yet know and haven't found any reference for it. I'm sure it is well documented somewhere, but I haven't found out how to search for it. Also, I apologize if I'm reasking an already answered question, I haven't found it here either.
What I would like to understand is the "admin: ..." syntax, which I met in several contexts:

In a template .html file:

```
<a href="{% url admin:todo_datetime_add %}">Add Todo items</a>
```

In a view function:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("admin:todo_item_changelist"))
```

I have gone through the djangoproject tutorial and the first 8 chapters of djangobook, and I didn't meet it there. I know, though, that in a reverse function a view function may be passed, and that {% %} template tags 'do something', but I have only seen dotted syntax used for these cases, so far. May it be that for referencing admin features, instead of the dotted syntax, we use this colon?

I would really appreciate some brief explanation on what it does.

Answer (score 7):

It's URL namespace. Admin docs: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-reverse-urls, general URL namespace docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces.

Comment: Hey i have a question, what's the difference between this colon and dot then? In django tutorial they mentioned that we can include url like this based on modules `include('polls.urls')`

Answer (score 3):

from django docs:

> If you'd like to retrieve a namespaced URL, specify the fully qualified name:
>
> {% url 'myapp:view-name' %}
> This will follow the normal namespaced URL resolution strategy, including using any hints >provided by the context as to the current application.